# in-browser SSH - IP address range

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

One of the options to `ssh` into the instance is `in-browser` ssh. It only works if I allow SSH from `0.0.0.0/0` IP range.

Is there a way to get the range of specific IP address range(s) from where GCP will establish `in-browser` SSH?

P.S.: I am not talking about SSH from my laptop. I am talking about `in-browser` SSH.

Comment: Are you looking for these IP ranges? https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/cloud.json (referenced here: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/access-apis-external-ip#ip-addr-defaults)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also wanted to restrict SSH access to in-browser only and found this

> The client IP address in the SSH connection will be part of the range **35.235.240.0/20**. This range is the pool of IP addresses used by IAP to proxy the connection from your browser to your instance. So, you can create a more restrictive VPC firewall rule allowing SSH connections only from this IP address range. As a result, only users allowed by IAP will be able to connect to VM using SSH.

(from https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/ssh-via-iap)

Answer (score 3):

The [Handling "Unable to connect on port 22" error message](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ssh-in-browser#ssherror) documentation states that you can get Google's IP address range using the [public SPF records](https://support.google.com/a/answer/60764).

Per the documentation, you'll need to run the three commands below from a linux VM instance:

```
nslookup -q=TXT _netblocks.google.com 8.8.8.8
nslookup -q=TXT _netblocks2.google.com 8.8.8.8
nslookup -q=TXT _netblocks3.google.com 8.8.8.8
```

You may need to install `dnsutils` on the vm instance to be able to use `dnslookup`.

I just tested it and got various ranges for IPv6 and IPv4. I believe this are the ranges you are searching for.

Comment: that doesn't look right. The doc you are referring to is named "Google IP address ranges for outbound mail servers"

Comment: @stkvtflw I'm more than rusty on this topic because the answer is 3 years old, but I believe I linked there because it showed how to get the IP ranges Google works with, sorry I can't help further. Also, if you didn't already, I would say opening a new question could help more than setting a bounty, because the new question might be picked up by a  GCP support member

Answer (score -1):

In order to allow SSH access from your laptop GCP console browser, you need to find your public IP address or external IP address of your LAN. You can check it in this [link](https://www.whatismyip.com/).Once you have your external IP address you need to create a FW to allow SSH access just from that external IP address.

Example:

gcloud compute firewall-rules create test-ssh-example \
--action allow \
--direction ingress \
--target-tags=[TAG] \     [You can specify a tag to apply this FW rule just to the VMs with the same tag. (optional)]
--rules tcp:22\
--source-ranges \
--priority 1000

With this option, only from that IP address you will be able to have SSH access to a VM instance.

Comment: this is exactly not what i asked though.

Comment: your public IP address has nothing to do with it

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you run the command `who` on your ssh session, to see where the connection is originating from?

The search the excellent [Cloud Platform documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs) to see if an automation to allow this already exists. Otherwise write one.

This is not the best place to do your firewalling from, as its one more configuration to keep up to date. I would recommend an application firewall, or just adding a rate limit to your existing firewall. The chances of someone logging into your servers if you use keys, is virtually 0, even with a 14 character random password, and rate limited new connections. If you use keys or a password manager (as you should), use `fail2ban`.

Comment: so, I'd have one IP address out of millions addresses on the internal GCP range. Not helpful.